Apt upgrade - some packages failed with 403 "InternalAVError"
Title says it all, failed to fetch 30 of the 91 outstanding packages on this server with the error:
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/... 403 InternalAVError [IP: 91.189.91.81 80]
Stumped when I web search for the term "InternalAVError" and get almost no results.
I dont believe there is antivirus software running on this server which is what I thought the error may be alluding to?

403 is a status code, and InternalAVError is a descriptive phrase for Internal error, which usually refers to the 500 code.

HTTP 403 Forbidden is a standard HTTP response code that means that
access to the requested resource is prohibited. The server understood
the request, but will not fulfill it. The most likely reasons for the
restriction are an attempt to access system resources of the web
server (for example, .htaccess or .htpasswd files) or files that were
closed using configuration files, a requirement for authentication by
non-HTTP means, for example, to access the content management system
or the section for registered users, or the server is not satisfied
with the client's IP address, for example, during blocking. Introduced
in HTTP/1.0.

Please add information about the OS version.

Ubuntu 22.04 (Jammy) is the version.
I can successfully wget a file from it's peer server on the same network, and was able to update the other 60 packages, so Im not sure why these ones are failing on this specific server.
I assumed InternalAVError was more specific than the general Internal Error but saw almost zero search results for that error which is why I decided to post my quesiton.

Manually trying with wget:
`wget http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/coreutils/coreutils_8.32-4.1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
--2024-10-30 13:40:50--
http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/c/coreutils/coreutils_8.32-4.1ubuntu1.2_amd64.deb
Resolving us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)... 91.189.91.83, 91.189.91.81, 2620:2d:4002:1::103, ...
Connecting to us.archive.ubuntu.com (us.archive.ubuntu.com)|91.189.91.83|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 403 InternalAVError
2024-10-30 13:40:50 ERROR 403: InternalAVError.`

I successfully executed wget, the file was received. I suppose that this may be related to your network settings (firewall or something similar). Unfortunately, I can't give more precise advice.
